# What is a phrase for being stuck at a job because of unwillingness to take a risk?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, idioms, idiom-requests

As a sample sentence

> I realize that I have <*insert phrase*> for too long. I need to quit this job and take my chances.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word for the feeling of dread/complacency that comes when starting something new](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/242285/word-for-the-feeling-of-dread-complacency-that-comes-when-starting-something-new) At this duplicate thread, hypernyms such as 'get cold feet', 'trepidation', and closer matches such as 'blank canvas paralysis' are given.

Comment: Or this? [What is the fear of the unknown called?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/272602/what-is-the-fear-of-the-unknown-called/272605#272605) (includes a secondary sense of _xenophobia_, so _being xenophobic_ is a hypernymic expression here. ... Or [What would you call a person who doesn't want to learn {/try} anything new?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28866/what-would-you-call-a-person-who-doesnt-want-to-learn-anything-new/28918#28918) ('stick-in-the-mud') I've also found the metaphor 'a ship that never left the port'.

Comment: You're *not [venturing out of your comfort zone.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22venturing+out+of+your+comfort+zone%22)

Comment: If you are "coasting" or "coasting along", that means that you've been figuratively letting inertia move you forward without expending any effort of your own.

Comment: Are you looking only for a _phrase_ and not a _word_?

Comment: I knew a phrase which was in relation to career and not just any change. I am hoping someone could help me recollect that.

Comment: The reasons for wanting to change jobs might be pertinent. It's one thing if you don't think you're being challenged, but quite another if you really dislike your job, but feel trapped.

Comment: (from the other replies: i do like "coasting" and "treading water".) some other ideas coming to my mind: "i've been stuck with tunnel vision" and "i've been resting on my laurels" and "stuck in a rut"

Answer (score 3):

There is a modern expression "comfort zone" so you could say "I realise I have been stuck in my comfort zone for too long".

Answer (score 2):

To **tread water** is literally to swim in place moving your legs and not going anywhere. But it has a common figurative meaning: as [Collins Cobuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tread-water) says, "If you say that someone is treading water, you mean that they are in an unsatisfactory situation where they are not progressing, but are just continuing doing the same things."

It captures the idea of repetition, lack of progress, just trying to keep alive without doing anything better. If you're literally treading water you're probably waiting for someone to throw you a line or a flotation device, and similarly in the figurative sense you're not taking control, you're just waiting to be rescued.

You would say: "I realize that I have been treading water for too long. I need to quit this job and take my chances."

Answer (score 0):

> I realize that I've **had cold feet** for too long. I need to quit
> this job and take my chances.

**cold feet** (n.)

> Informal
> A loss or lack of courage or confidence; an onset of
> uncertainty or fear [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/cold-feet)

> **Cold feet** is a phrase which refers to a person not going through with
> an action, particularly one which requires long term commitment, due
> to fear, uncertainty, and doubt.
>
> **Definitions (psychological)**
> A loss or lack of courage or confidence;
> an onset of uncertainty or fear
> Too fearful to undertake or complete
> an action
> Timidity that prevents the continuation of a course of
> action
>
> **Etymology**
>
> The origin of the term itself has been largely attributed to American
> author Stephen Crane, who added the phrase, in 1896, to the second
> edition of his short novel, *Maggie: A Girl of the Streets*. Crane
> writes, "I knew this was the way it would be. They got **cold feet**." The
> term is present in "Seed Time and Harvest" by Fritz Reuter published
> in 1862. Kenneth McKenzie, a former professor of Italian at
> Princeton University attributed the first use of the phrase to the
> play Volpone produced by Ben Jonson in 1605. The true origin and
> first usage of the phrase remains debated and unconfirmed as
> exemplified above. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_feet)

> Likewise, my knowledge of the concept of approach-avoidance conflicts
> helped me to recognize that the frightening aspects of my dream...was
> a normal expression of my **cold feet** about getting "married," so to
> speak, to a new job. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/about_wholeness/hfDgDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=new%20job%20cold%20feet&pg=PT152&printsec=frontcover).

> What if I'm about to take the offer—but am getting **cold feet**?
> Let's fully acknowledge those nerves, and put them into context.
> [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Workparent/mi3wDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=cold%20feet%20).

Answer (score 0):

You can say

> I realize that I have been **faint hearted** for too long. I need to quit this job and take my chances.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/faint_heart) gives

> **faint heart**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> A person who lacks courage or conviction.
>
> *First-class professionals prospered in that hostile environment, while faint hearts fell by the wayside.*

Lexico also gives the proverb

> **faint heart never won fair lady**
>
> Timidity will prevent you from achieving your objective.

Answer (score 0):

Stagnating too long , not growing , remained complacent,  unable to thrive

PS : it looks like inability to thrive in a position might be a reflection of self rather than the position

Answer (score 0):

StuartF and Canadian_Yankee gave great answers that resonate with me.

Some other ideas coming to my mind:

- "stuck in a rut"
- "stuck with tunnel vision"
- "resting on my laurels"
- "resting and vesting"

There is also the related notion of a "dead-end job".

Answer (score 0):

"stuck in a rut" -- because you have no progression you can make if you are stuck in a hole in the ground

> I realize that I have been stuck in a rut for too long. I need to quit this job and take my chances.